# The JVM should have exited but did not

Tags: jmeter, jvm, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed

During Distributed testing with Jmeter 3.3 in non gui mode i'm getting error as, how can I fix this :

I'm using same version of JMeter and JDK on Master as well as Slave machines.

The JVM should have exited but did not.
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
Thread[main,5,main],

```
stackTrace:java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead0
java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead
java.net.SocketInputStream#read
java.net.SocketInputStream#read
java.io.BufferedInputStream#fill
java.io.BufferedInputStream#read
java.io.DataInputStream#readByte
sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall#executeCall
sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef#invoke
java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler#invokeRemoteMethod
java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler#invoke
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19#rrunTest
org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine#runTest at line:149
org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner#start at line:132
org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner#start at line:149
org.apache.jmeter.JMeter#runNonGui at line:1005
org.apache.jmeter.JMeter#startNonGui at line:910
org.apache.jmeter.JMeter#start at line:538
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke0
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl#invoke
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl#invoke
java.lang.reflect.Method#invoke
org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver#main at line:248
```

Comment: Can you write a small, self-contained program which reproduces this issue? If you post it here it will help others to investigage the problem. See the help on [mcve].

Answer (score 11):

I strongly recommend using this jmeter property:

```
jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true
```

documented [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous).  These Chinese language web pages [link](https://www.bbsmax.com/A/QW5Yb8q3dm/) [link](https://blog.csdn.net/lijing742180/article/details/80901933) tipped me off.

You can add `-Jjmeterengine.force.system.exit=true` on the command line when launching JMeter, or add `jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true` to JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.properties.

**How I Confirmed This Fix**

With JMeter 5.1 and java version "1.8.0_231" on MS-Win10, we're using a customized version of this [JMeter InfluxDB backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener).
After my 60 second test run from the command line (jmeter.bat -n -t plan.jtl), the command line hung after displaying this output (very similar to op):

```
Tidying up ...    @ Wed Jan 29 14:41:04 CST 2020 (1580330464874)
... end of run
The JVM should have exited but did not.
The following non-daemon threads are still running (DestroyJavaVM is OK):
Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main], stackTrace:
Thread[pool-2-thread-3,5,main], stackTrace:sun.misc.Unsafe#park
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport#parkNanos
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#awaitNanos
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue#take
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue#take
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#getTask
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#run
java.lang.Thread#run

Thread[pool-2-thread-4,5,main], stackTrace:sun.misc.Unsafe#park
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport#parkNanos
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#awaitNanos
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue#take
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue#take
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#getTask
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#run
java.lang.Thread#run

Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main], stackTrace:sun.misc.Unsafe#park
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport#parkNanos
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject#awaitNanos
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue#take
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue#take
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#getTask
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#runWorker
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker#run
java.lang.Thread#run
```

After modifying my command line as follows, jmeter.bat cleanly exited instead of hanging and all the ugly stack trace went away too:

```
jmeter.bat -n -Jjmeterengine.force.system.exit=true -t plan.jtl
```

To confirm that the problem was caused by our customized [JMeter InfluxDB backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener), I removed it from the .jmx and I also removed the jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true.  No hang, no ugly stacktrace (I actually love stacktraces).

I have not taken the next step to discover whether the problem is with the official [JMeter InfluxDB backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) or with our customized variant, which is not (and will never be) available publicly.

Should mention one gap in this story.  I feel this test conclusively points to our customized backend listener (or jmeter's).  However, its odd that none of the threads in the above thread dump seem to belong to the backend listener.  So I applaud that JMeter did the right thing by dumping the stack trace -- few other apps go to the  extent of auto-dumping when appropriate for troubleshooting.  But in this case, perhaps that jmeter auto-dump code needs to be enhanced, because it did not point to the culprit backend listener code.  Anyone over there at Apache listening in on this?

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your JMeter engine(s) is(are) overloaded therefore cannot gracefully shut down running threads when you request them to do so.

1. Make sure you follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. The very first "best practice" states [Always use latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) or whatever latest version is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page
3. Make sure your JMeter instances have enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM and so on. You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this if you don't have other monitoring software in place/in mind.
4. Take a [thread dump](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-take-thread-dumps-7-options) and examine it - this way you will know where exactly your test is stuck
5. Introduce reasonable timeout values in [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) so in case when server fails to respond JMeter wouldn't wait infinitely but rather fail with an error

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults]
6. And finally (however I wouldn't recommend this) you can [suppress this check](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.exit.check.pause=-1
   ```

   if you go for this keep in mind that you may run into a situation when JMeter slaves will still be trying to execute something even after your test ends so you will need to kill and restart the processes manually or using a script.

Comment: @DT, For #6 jmeter.exit.check.pause=-1, in distributed mode this property should be set on master only or both master and slaves.